# gmail api: get latest 2 emails from thread

Tags: python, gmail-api

The code below retrieves the latest email in the thread. How do I retrieve the latest 2 emails in the thread? Thanks in advance.

```
messages = service.users().threads().list(userId='me').execute().get('threads', [])

for message in messages:
    if search in message['snippet']:
        # add/modify the following lines:
        thread = service.users().threads().get(userId='me', id=message['id'], fields='messages(id,internalDate)').execute() #.get( [])
        last = len(thread['messages']) - 1
        message_id = thread['messages'][last]['id']

        # non-modified code:
        full_message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message_id, format="raw").execute()
        msg_str = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(full_message['raw'].encode('ASCII'))
        mime_msg = email.message_from_bytes(msg_str)
        y = re.findall(r'Delivered-To: (\S+)', str(mime_msg))
        print(y[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

- The line `last = len(thread['messages']) - 1` specifies that you want to retrieve the last message from a thread
- Consequently, to retrieve the prelast message, you need to specify `prelast = len(thread['messages']) - 2`
- And respectively `prelast_message_id = thread['messages'][prelast]['id']`
- Now, you can push both `last` and `prelast` message Ids into an array and perform your `# non-modified code` in a `for` loop on both message ids.